# Netsuite saved search sum two chart of accounts

Tags: netsuite

how do you sum two chart of accounts in Netsuite saved search?

In the criteria field i have selected Account and then the Account Name in Description. Then in Results tab i was trying to create a formula to sum them, but i am not sure of the syntax?
the chart of account names are Permanents and Casuals
so i tried ({Permanents.Amount}+{Casuals.Amount})using Formula Currency and Sum in the Summary column.
It doesn't recognise these field names, so not sure what the syntax is?

thanks

Comment: What is the saved search Type?  Typically this sort of thing would be achieved by selecting the accounts you want to sum under criteria, and then just sum the balance in results.  The fact that both accounts are included in criteria would automatically mean both are included in results.

Comment: it's a transaction type. just selecting both as criteria and then selecting Amount and sum in Results does not work.